# custom async validation not working when returning a promise

Tags: validation, angular, promise, rxjs, formbuilder

I'm calling the web api to check if an urlalias is available, for this task I'm using a httpservice in my async validator.
The issue is that when the validator is called, all the correct code path is performed (all the `console.log()` run and behave as expected).

Whether the promise from the validation returns/resolves to null or an `{ 'isUrlAliasActivityMainAvailable': true }`, the controller always shows an error object as following, thus keeping the form state as invalid, why (bloody hell!)?

I'm using: angular:2.1.0 and rxjs:5.0.0-beta.12

[image]

This is my formbuilder:

```
this.formBuilder.group({
//...
"urlAliasActivityMain":[null,[ ValidatorsZr.isUrlAliasActivityMainAvailableAsyncValidator(this.httpActivityService)]],
});
```

This is my validator:

```
   public static isUrlAliasActivityMainAvailableAsyncValidator(httpActivityService: HttpActivityService) {
        return function (control: FormControl): Promise<any> | Observable<any> {

            const promise = new Promise<any>(
                (resolve, reject) => {
                    httpActivityService.isUrlAliasActivityMainAvailable(control.value)
                        .subscribe(
                        (data: any) => {
                            console.log("isUrlAliasActivityMainAvailableAsyncValidator");
                            console.log(data);
                            if (data == false) {
                                console.log("data == false");
                                resolve({ 'isUrlAliasActivityMainAvailable': true });
                            }
                            else {
                                console.log("data == true");
                                resolve(null);
                            }
                        },

                    )
                });

            return promise;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your async validator is listed in the synchronous validators location in the array and is being incorrectly evaluated.

`[objectValue, synchronous validators, asynchronous validators]`

> control(formState: Object, validator?: ValidatorFn|ValidatorFn[],
>   asyncValidator?: AsyncValidatorFn|AsyncValidatorFn[]) : FormControl
>   Construct a new FormControl with the given formState,validator, and
>   asyncValidator.
>
> formState can either be a standalone value for the form control or an
>   object that contains both a value and a disabled status.

To correct it, move your validator to the appropriate array location:

```
this.formBuilder.group({
//...
"urlAliasActivityMain":[null, null, ValidatorsZr.isUrlAliasActivityMainAvailableAsyncValidator(this.httpActivityService)],
});
```

Comment: omg, so ashamed of me! Thanks for your your help, you've been a great time saver!

Comment: I wasted about 4 hours because of this very thing.

Comment: this saved the future lol, was battling with it for a day now, not knowing it was the location i placed it