# asyncValidators return observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-forms

I try return Observable (as async Validators)

```
asyncValidators(control:FormControl): Observable<any>{
        return new Observable<any>(observer => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                if(control.value === 'Example')
                    observer.next({example:true})
                else
                    observer.next(null)
            }, 1500)
        observer.complete()
    })
}
```

And use it inside a **Formbuilder.group** as:

```
'username': ['Exam',[Validators.required, this.asyncValidators]]
```

But this function's never fire, what am I doing wrong here ?

### Update:

I'm wrong I simply put my async inside sync array so solution is:

```
'username': ['Max',Validators.required, this.asyncValidators],
```

Comment: As far as I know, it expects a promise, not an observable.

Comment: thanks, I think Promise == Observable... I think it return Promise or Observable but donno why this isn't fired

Comment: @Dinistro, it can actually be either. In the current implementation async validator's result internally gets converted to a promise explicitly.

Comment: @Eee, couple more notes:
1) Do not create observable with `new` keyword unless you're absolutely sure about what you're doing. There are tons of different static helpers to do that. For this example it would be Observable.create();
2) You start something with setTimeout() and then immediately complete observable with observer.complete(). Whatever happens inside timeout doesn't matter anymore, it will not go anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [custom async validation not working when returning a promise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40756441/custom-async-validation-not-working-when-returning-a-promise)